# Spring WS I/O error: Not in GZIP format

Tags: java, client, gzip, spring-ws

Im using Spring WS to call a Web Service. For now, I am running the Web service on SoapUI. Also, due that I have to send and receive complex objects I'm marshalling and unmarshalling the request and response.

For generating WSDL sources I am using jaxws-maven-plugin.

When i call the Web service, i got this error:

```
14:38:21,503 - ERROR - Authentication.startAuthentication(141) | 000000001319805501206 - Error in authentication process -  org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOption: I/O error: Not in GZIP format; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
14:38:21,505 - DEBUG - Authentication.startAuthentication(142) | 000000001319805501206 - Error StackTrace. org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Not in GZIP format; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:432)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:253)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:245)
    ...
```

It is like spring is interpreting that Web Service response it is in gzip format. Is there anyway to tell spring that it doesn't?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. I did not find the source of the problem, but I have fixed the error just upgrading the libreries I was using. Now, I am using last version of: `jaxb-impl`, `spring-ws-core-tiger` and `spring-oxm-tiger`